# CSS Position element relative to two other

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to position an element horizontally in relation to one element and vertically to another using only CSS?
I am trying to add a dropdown menu to my navbar. However, the submenu does not align properly.
I want to position element A so that its left edge aligns with element B's left edge, but I want element A's top edge to be aligned with element C's bottom edge.

Essentially, I want it under header, aligned with list element (image edited):

[image]

I have the following code:

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline;          /* Makes list items inline */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: absolute;       /* Enables positioning */
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  left: 0;                  /* Align left edge - SHOULD BE ALIGNED WITH ANCESTOR LIST ITEM */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li:hover>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Now, to make the positioning do something, I have to select the element to which the positioning will be done. But, if I do it with list element, the submenu will be too far up, because it is positioned under the list element, and the header has some padding.

```css
#header li {
    position: relative; /* Positioning will be relative to the ANCESTOR LIST ITEM */
}
```

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline;          /* Makes list items inline */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
  position: relative;       /* Positioning will be relative to the ANCESTOR LIST ITEM */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: absolute;       /* Enables positioning */
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  left: 0;                  /* Align left edge - SHOULD BE ALIGNED WITH ANCESTOR LIST ITEM */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li:hover>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This is the result: aligned with list element

[image]

And if I do it with the header, the submenu will be aligned with the left of the entire header, which is not what I want.

```css
#header {
    position: relative; /* Positioning will be relative to the HEADER */
}
```

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
  position: relative;       /* Positioning will be relative to the HEADER */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline;          /* Makes list items inline */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: absolute;       /* Enables positioning */
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  left: 0;                  /* Align left edge - SHOULD BE ALIGNED WITH ANCESTOR LIST ITEM */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li:hover>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

This is what it looks like: under header

[image]

So, what I want is the "top: 100%;" to be related to the entire header and "left: 0;" to be related to the list element of which the submenu is a child.

I hope my question was clear. I could not find anyone who has asked this question before. I'm sorry I could not put pictures or more links in the question because this is my first question ever, so I do not have enough reputation.

Thanks for reading my question, I hope it will get answered soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position `.submenu` relatively to the header, and then take advantage of `left: auto`'s behavior.

Then, `.submenu` will be an absolutely positioned element whose `left`, `width` and `right` properties are all `auto`.

Therefore, according to [§10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width),

> If all three of 'left', 'width', and 'right' are 'auto': First set any
>   'auto' values for 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' to 0. Then, if the
>   'direction' property of the element establishing the [static-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#static-position)
>   containing block is 'ltr' set 'left' to the [static position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#static-position) and apply
>   rule number three below

That static position is defined as

> The static position for 'left' is the distance from the left edge of
>   the containing block to the left margin edge of a hypothetical box
>   that would have been the first box of the element if its 'position'
>   property had been 'static' and 'float' had been 'none'. The value is
>   negative if the hypothetical box is to the left of the containing
>   block.

So let's remove `position: absolute` and see:

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
  position: relative;       /* Positioning will be relative to the HEADER */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline;          /* Makes list items inline */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: static;
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Effectively, since `.submenu` is a block and its parent is inline, `submenu` will appear at the beginning of the following line.

To prevent that, `.submenu` must generate a block container. Inline-level block containers can be generated with `display: inline-block`.

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
  position: relative;       /* Positioning will be relative to the HEADER */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline-block;    /* Makes list items inline-block */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: static;
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Now the `.submenu` has the desired static position for left.

Therefore, if adding `position: absolute` again, it works as desired:

```css
#header{
  padding: 0.125em;     
  background: #eee;         /* Styling for clarity */
  position: relative;       /* Positioning will be relative to the HEADER */
}
nav{
  display: inline;          /* Makes nav inline */
}
h1{
  display: inline;          /* Makes the main title inline */
}
#header ul{
  padding:0;                /* Clears the space around the list */
  display: inline;          /* Makes lists inline */
}
#header li{
  display: inline-block;    /* Makes list items inline-block */
  list-style-type: none;    /* Removes bullets */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu>li{
  display: block;           /* Makes submenu list items behave normally */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: none;            /* Hides the submenu */
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;                /* Position directly under - SHOULD BE UNDER HEADER */
  background: #ccc;         /* Styling for clarity */
}
#header ul>li>.submenu{
  display: block;           /* Shows the submenu */
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>
          <h1>
            <img>TITLE
          </h1>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
          <li><a>PAGE</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>PAGE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

To summarize, the fix is

```css
#header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#header ul > li > .submenu {
  left: auto; /* Initial value */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/td6Las4x/

Just add "position:relative" only for the "#header", remove "left:0" for "#header ul > li > .submenu" and "display: inline-block;" for "#header li"

```
#header li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked! Could you explain why making the element an inline block solved it?

Comment: Inline elements cannot have a width and height set, but inline-block is like a mix of inline and block properties, respects width and height properties and allows the elements inside to sit to its left and right.